# Does non mevushal wine make the vessels containing it treif?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, stam-yenam

As per halacha and many other questions here, non-Jews touching (etc.) non mevushal wine can cause the wine to become non kosher.

Does this have any effect of the vessels holding the wine, kashrut-wise?

For example, say you bring non mevushal wine to the table at a kosher hotel, and then a non Jewish worker touches it. Are you simply prohibited from drinking that wine, or did you cause kashrut problems in the glass, and/or whatever the glass is washed with etc. etc.?

I ask about this kind of wine specifically because I thought it might be different than other non-kosher products, as it seems to me that this is not inherently un-kosher, but rather something that has become unfit for consumption due to external concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The vessels definitely *can* become assur and they *can* make other wine assur to drink, although they will be muttar bihanaa, i.e. you can sell it. Another difference is this wine which becomes assur from the vessels will be nullified in sixty. There are various details that matter though. See the Shulchan Aruch [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.137?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all). It depends on whether the vessel is made for storing wine or not, and if it is not made to store wine, the amount of time the new wine stays in the vessel will matter. There is also a siman found [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.135?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) which discusses which types of vessels are suspect or not to having been used for storing wine.

In your specific example, being that the bottle is made to store wine and the cup is not, they will have two different laws. Assuming the bottle was touched by someone who causes the wine to become assur, after which it is poured into a cup. Now, both are emptied, dried and refilled with kosher wine. The wine in the bottle becomes assur immediately, and the wine in the cup will only become assur if left there for twenty four hours.