# "Non-Kosher" wine vs. Other "non-kosher foods"

Tags: kashrut-kosher, grapes-wine

If I have a cup/plate/utensil and I put/use non-kosher meat in/with it, or make/place a forbidden mixture of milk and meat in it, I will have a problem with the future use of that cup (I know, the details are complex about exactly what has to be done for there to be a problem but for this hypothetical, whatever I put in the cup or on the dish is enough to do the trick).

If I put non-kosher wine in the cup (or pour it into the pot, or stir it with a spoon etc) do I have the same problem with that object/utensil which requires "kashering"?

Is the inherent "non-kosherness" of wine the same as that of foods (which might be a transfer of taste...I don't recall)?

***Distinguishing cases***

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64163/does-non-mevushal-wine-make-the-vessels-containing-it-treif) question discusses non-mevushal wine which was touched by a non-Jew. To my mind, that means that it was initially supervised as "kosher" but lost that status. I am asking about wine which never had any supervision (though I don't know if that is any different -- if there is any concern over the kosherness of wine, ever, or if the only concern is its potential for having been used for idolatry).

Comment: Is there anything to make you think wine might be different than other foods here?

Comment: I am not sure that non mevushal wine been handled by a non observant Jew does the same thing but in regards to wine that was made to be bone kosher possibly yes. I was once Co,sidering renting a wine press and asked the cry about this and they said it wouldn't be kosher to use a wine press that had been used to make non kosher wine

Comment: @scimonster one way wine is different is it becomes batel 1 in 6 parts while other things must be 1 in 60 parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch defines these laws in 47:16-22 - [סימן מ"ז - הלכות סתם יינם והכשר הכלים ממנו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0046_L2)

Roughly translated - with the source underneath:

Utensils that are not used for long-term wine storage, and non-Kosher wine was in them for less than 24 hours, then you rinse them 3 times and they are permitted. (Does not apply to tarred or earthenware utensils.)

> **סעיף ט"ז**: 
>   כֵּלִים שֶׁל סְתָם יֵינָם, אִם הֵם כֵּלִים שֶׁאֵין הַדֶּרֶךְ לְהַחְזִיק בָּהֶם יַיִן אֶלָּא זְמַן קָצָר, וְגַם לֹא הָיָה בָּהֶם הַיַּיִן מֵעֵת לְעֵת, בֵּין שֶׁהֵם שֶׁל עוֹר בֵּין שֶׁהֵם שֶׁל עֵץ וְשֶׁל זְכוּכִית וְשֶׁל אֶבֶן וְשֶׁל מַתֶּכֶת, אִם אֵינָם מְזֻפָּתִין, מְדִיחָן הֵיטֵב בְּמַיִם שָׁלֹשׁ פְּעָמִים וּמֻתָּרִים. וְאִם הֵם מְזֻפָּתִין, יֵשׁ לָהֶם דִּין אַחֵר. וְכֵן כְּלִי חֶרֶס יֵשׁ לָהֶם דִּין אַחֵר. ‏

Long-term storage utensils need *Iruy* - i.e. filled with water to overflowing and kept full for 24 hours. Empty after 24 hours and repeat twice more.

Some say that if the non-Kosher wine was in the long-term utensils for more than 24-hours then they need to be Kashered by immersing in boiling hot water.

> **סעיף י"ז:**
>   כֵּלִים הָעֲשׂוּיִים לְהַכְנִיס בָּהֶם יַיִן לְקִיּוּם, דְּהַיְנוּ שֶׁמְיַחֲדִין אוֹתָן לְהַחְזִיק בָּהֶם יַיִן לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת שְׁלשָׁה יָמִים, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהַכְּלִי הוּא שֶׁל יִשְֹרָאֵל, וְהָעוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים הֶחְזִיק בּוֹ אֶת הַיַּיִן רַק זְמַן מֻעָט, מִכָּל מָקוֹם צָרִיךְ הֶכְשֵׁר עַל יְדֵי עִרוּי דְּהַיְנוּ מְמַלְּאִים אֶת הַכְּלִי מַיִם עַל כָּל גְּדוֹתָיו, וְיַעֲמֹד כָּךְ לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת עֶשְׂרִים וְאַרְבַּע שָׁעוֹת, מֵעֵת לְעֵת, וְאַחַר כָּךְ שׁוֹפֵךְ אֶת הַמַּיִם וְנוֹתֵן בּוֹ מַיִם שְׁנִיִּים, וְיַעֲמֹד כָּךְ לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת מֵעֵת לְעֵת, וְכֵן עוֹשֶׂה פַּעַם שְׁלִישִׁית. וְאֵין צְרִיכִין שֶׁיִּהְיוּ הַשְּׁלשָׁה מֵעֵת לְעֵת דַּוְקָא רְצוֹפִין. וְאִם עָמְדוּ בּוֹ הַמַּיִם כַּמָּה יָמִים וְלֹא שְׁפָכָם, לֹא עָלָה לוֹ אֶלָּא לְמֵעֵת לְעֵת אֶחָד. יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים, דְּאִם הַיַּיִן הָיָה בּוֹ מֵעֵת לְעֵת, לֹא מִתְכַּשֵּׁר בְּעֵרוּי, מִשּׁוּם דְּכָבוּשׁ כִּמְבֻשָּׁל וּבָעֵי הַגְעָלָה. וּבְמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵין צֹרֶךְ גָּדוֹל, יֵשׁ לְהַחְמִיר כֵּן. ‏

Glass utensils need only be rinsed 3 times, even if they were used for long term storage.

> **סעיף י"ח:**
>   כְּלֵי זְכוּכִית כֵּיוָן שֶׁהֵם חֲלָקִים וְקָשִׁים, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁמַּכְנִיסִין בָּהֶם יַיִן לְקִיּוּם, סָגֵּי לְהוּ בַּהֲדָחַה שָׁלֹשׁ פְּעָמִים. ‏

Utensils that are still damp after the Kosher wine was emptied out, need only be rinsed 3 times if a non-Jew touched them, even if they are long-term storage utensils.

> סעיף י"ט:
>   כְּלִי שֶׁהָיָה בּוֹ יַיִן שֶׁלָּנוּ וְעֵרוּ אֶת הַיַּיִן, וּבְעוֹד שֶׁהָיָה הַכְּלִי טוֹפֵחַ עַל מְנָת לְהַטְפִיחַ נָגַע שָׁם עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים סָגֵּי לֵהּ בַּהֲדָחָה שָׁלֹשׁ פְּעָמִים, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא כְּלִי שֶׁמַּכְנִיסִין בּוֹ לְקִיּוּם. ‏

All the above applies to cold use only. If the wine was hot then the utensil needs to be Kashered in boiling water.

> **סעיף כ':**
>   הָא דְּמַהֲנִי הֲדָחָה אוֹ עֵרוּי, זֶהוּ כְּשֶׁלֹּא נִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בּוֹ יַיִן רַק בְּצוֹנֵן. אֲבָל אִם נִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בּוֹ בְּחַמִּין, צָרִיךְ הַגְעָלָה כְּמוֹ מִשְּׁאָר אִסּוּרִין. ‏

The above does not apply to utensils used in the winery; those need Rabbinic guidance how to Kasher.

> **סעיף כ"א:**
>   כְּלֵי הַגַּת אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין מַכְנִיסִין בָּהֶם יַיִן לְקִיּוּם, כֵּיוָן שֶׁמִּשְׁתַּמְּשִׁין בָּהֶם יַיִן בְּשֶׁפַע, חֲמִירֵי, וּצְרִיכִין שְׁאֵלַת חָכָם אֵיךְ לְהַכְשִׁירָן. ‏

Any vessels that were not used for wine for 12 months or longer are Kosher, even if they were used with water during that period.

> **סעיף כ"ב:**
>   כָּל הַכֵּלִים שֶׁנִּתְיַשְׁנוּ שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר חֹדֶשׁ, מֻתָּרִים, כִּי בְּוַדַּאי כָּלָה כָּל לַחְלוּחִית יַיִן שֶׁבָּהֶם. וַאֲפִלּוּ נָתַן לְתוֹכָן מַיִם תּוֹךְ שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר חֹדֶשׁ, אֵין בְּכָךְ כְּלוּם.‏